# Print out every other character in an array only using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm having an issue with a programming excercise using pointers in C++.

My goal is to only print every other character in my array while only using pointers.

This for loop below works to print out all the characters from my array but I've been having issues only printing out every other character.

I've tried incrementing i by doing `i+=2` but that only prints out very stange characters that have nothing to do with my array.

This code isn't all of my code. It's just a snippet of it to understand how to do this.

```
char myChar[13] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'H', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'k', '\0'};
char myChar2[13] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'H', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'k', '\0'};




char *temp5 = myChar;
char *temp6 = myChar2;



// Prints out all characters from array using pointers
cout<<"\n\nThis is the original element for the char array.\n\n";
cout<<"\t";
for(int i = 0; i< 13; i++)
{
    *temp6 = *temp5;
    temp5++;

    cout<<*temp6;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid - but you are not "using only pointers". I see you are using `i` variable... Think one more time on how to do it with "using only pointers"...

Comment: I was vague in my explenation. I meant to say that after initializing the static arrays I cannot have the use of any [] brackets or arrays unless I was doing dynamic new array declerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following is what you want:

```
char myChar[13] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'H', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'k', '\0'};
char *temp5 = myChar;


// Prints out all characters from array using pointers
cout<<"\n\nThis is the original element for the char array.\n\n";
cout<<"\t";
for(int i = 0; i< 13/2; i++) // 13/2 to only increment through half the array
{
    cout<<*temp5;
     temp5+=2; // to skip every other character
}
```

You want to only loop through half the array, so that is taken care of with 13/2, and to skip those extra characters, we increment the pointer by 2.

Comment: This definitely works! Thanks :D

I just have one issue now. When I go to duplicate the for loop so i can print out the full char array and then in another line only print out every other letter I'm still getting funny characters instead of the output. 

It seems like I can only have one of the for loops but I truthfully need two.

Comment: @JHancock probably it means that you are reading out of the array's bounds, and the reason could be that between the 2 loops you have forgotten to reset the pointer `temp5` back to the initial position of `myChar`. By the way, if this answer solved your problem please remember to mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick on its left.

Comment: @Fabio Turati Ok thanks! I just did it.

Sorry for so many questions.

When you say reset the pointer temp5, do you mean to use the delete function to do that?

I'm still a little lost.

Comment: @JHancock No, deleting it would be wrong (you should never `delete` something that doesn't come from `new`!). What I meant is that `temp5` is used to access the characters of your string, starting from the beginning and increasing it on the go. So if you want to have a second loop which does something else with the characters, you must put a `temp5 = myChar;` between them. Similar to the line `char *temp5 = myChar;` at the beginning, but this time you don't need to declare the type `char*` as the variable already exists, you just have to assign the initial value again.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good, but here's an alternative in the spirit of "using only pointers."  This prints out every character, but I'm sure you can figure out how to modify it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using std::cout;

int main(void)
{
  static const char message[] = "John Hancock!";

  for ( const char* p = message; p < message + sizeof(message); ++p ) {
    cout << *p;
  }

  cout << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```